# Improve the speed of this MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql, asterisk

I am using PHP and MYSQL to graph call concurenncy from an Asterisk CDR database,

I currently use the following prepared statement:

```
$query=$cdrdb->prepare('select count(acctid) from cdr where calldate between ? and ? or DATE_ADD(calldate, INTERVAL duration SECOND)  between ? and ?');
```

and then the following foreach loop to enter the variables:

```
 foreach ($timerange as $startdatetime){
    $start=$startdatetime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $enddatetime=new DateTime($start);
    $enddatetime->Add($interval);
    $end=$enddatetime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    if(!$query->execute(array($start, $end, $start, $end))){
            echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }
    if (!($res = $query->fetchall())) {
            echo "Getting result set failed: ";
    }
    array_push($callsperinterval,$res[0][0]);

    }
```

Timerange can be every hour for a day, every day for a month or every week for a year.

the calldate column is marked as an index column.

The table currently holds 122000 records.

the result of running an EXPLAIN on the query:

```
mysql> explain select count(acctid) from cdr where calldate between '2014-10-02 23:30:00' and '2014-11-03 00:00:00' or DATE_ADD(calldate, INTERVAL duration SECOND)  between '2014-10-02 23:30:00' and '2014-11-03 00:00:00';
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra              |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cdr   | ALL  | calldate      | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 123152 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

A single run of the query takes around 0.14s so for a 24 hour period with an hourly interval the script should finish in about 3.36 seconds, but it ends up taking about 12 seconds

Currently the whole process can take up to 20 seconds to run for a 24 hour period,can anyone please help me to improve the speed of this query?

Comment: Where's your question?

Comment: How slow is the query?

Comment: Added information to original question

Comment: So, am I right in thinking that you are running the same query over an over again?

Comment: did you take a look at the execution plan of the query?

Comment: I suggest you forget about the PHP for now, and just focus on the mysql. Let's assume timerange is "every day for a month".

Comment: @Olli I added the result of an explain

Comment: Do you have query_cache enabled and configured?

Comment: AFAIK this: `DATE_ADD(calldate, INTERVAL duration SECOND)` is your performance bottleneck as it is performing a calculation on each subset row for comparison.

Comment: @Latheesan - Yes, query_cache is enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is the bottleneck in your query:

```
DATE_ADD(calldate, INTERVAL duration SECOND)
```

This is because MySQL is performing "math" on <strike>each row of the first subset determined from your first `WHERE` condition</strike> **every row on your entire table that didn't match the first part of your `WHERE` statement since you are using `WHERE OR`, not `WHERE AND`.**

I assumed your table looks something a little like:

```
acctid | calldate            | duration
========================================
1      | 2014-12-01 17:55:00 | 300
... etc.
```

Consider rewriting your schema such that you are not using intervals that MySQL must calculate for each row, but full DateTime columns that MySQL can perform immediate comparisons on:

```
acctid | calldate            | duration_end
==================================================
1      | 2014-12-01 17:55:00 | 2014-12-01 18:00:00
```

To rewrite this schema, you can make that new column and then do (this may take a while to process but will serve you well in the long run):

```
UPDATE cdr SET duration_end = DATE_ADD(calldate, INTERVAL duration SECOND);
```

Then scrap the `duration` column and rewrite your application to save into the new column!

Your resulting query will be:

```
select count(acctid) from cdr where calldate > ? and (calldate < ? or duration_end between ? and ?)
```

Assuming that nothing can change in the schema, then you're stuck with that function. However, you can try having MySQL work with subsets so that it's not doing math on so many rows:

```
select
    count(acctid)
from
    cdr
where
    calldate > ? and
        (calldate < ? or DATE_ADD(calldate, INTERVAL duration SECOND) between ? and ?)
```

I can't guarantee much of a performance increase from this solution although it may be a noticeable one depending on your data set.

Comment: The application is Asterisk, so changing it to write in a different way would be a challenge (though not impossible). I would prefer a solution where I can use the standard mysql table structure.

Comment: @JurgensKrause So you want to improve your query without changing anything. [It's pretty well known that using MySQL functions on large ranges is problematic.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281072/which-mysql-date-query-performs-better) Maybe you could think of making a hook for this app that saves that extra column upon row creation. Hold for an alternative, I think I can come up with something.

Comment: Asterisk actually does support custom entries, but I would like to keep it simple for other people who want to use my software. If I cannot find a better alternative, I will be forced to use this solution. I will give it  a try anyway, and see how it performs. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Your solution brings it down to about 8 seconds for the 24 hour period.

Comment: @JurgensKrause I've given you a few alternatives and updated my original query. You should also make sure you compare the unit benchmarks to the 24 hour benchmark by getting the performance time of each hour interval in the 24 hour period. You may be miscalculating by using a best-case hour unit.

Comment: The second option works great. It brought the script time down to about 3 seconds. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JurgensKrause I'm almost surprised but happy it helped. The data set must get dramatically smaller after using `calldate > ?`. You can also look into indexing your `calldate` column if you're looking to improve performance a bit more. Cheers!

Comment: There are no any challenges in dooing call_end_time column for asterisk cdr. Just use simple trigger.

Answer (score 0):

For asterisk cdrs you can just do like this

Let say you used:

```
$query=$cdrdb->prepare('select count(acctid) from cdr where calldate between ? and ? or DATE_ADD(calldate, INTERVAL duration SECOND)  between ? and ?');

$query->execute(array($start, $end, $start, $end))
```

You have use like this

```
$query=$cdrdb->prepare('select count(acctid) from cdr where calldate between ? and DATE_ADD(?, interval ? SECOND) and (calldate between ? and ? or DATE_ADD(calldate, INTERVAL duration SECOND)  between ? and ?) 
');

$MAX_CALL_LENGHT_POSIBLE = 60*60*10; # usualy 10 hr is not reachable on most calls. If you limit it in call, you can decrease to even less values

$query->execute(array($start, $end,$MAX_CALL_LENGHT_POSIBLE,$start,$end $start, $end))
```

So just first limit query to interval where that stop_time can be.

But much simple will be add column call_end_time and create trigger

```
  DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS cdr_insert_trigger;
  DELIMITER //
  CREATE TRIGGER cdr_insert_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON cdr
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    Set NEW.call_end_time=DATE_ADD(OLD.calldate,interval OLD.duration second);
  END//
  DELIMITER ;
```

Sure you need create index on BOTH calldate and call_end_time column and use Union instead of OR(otherwise one part will not use index)

Answer (score 0):

If disk space is less important than speed, try:

```
ALTER TABLE cdr ROW_FORMAT = FIXED;
```